# Get Device names of surrounding WIFI devices without authentication

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng, host-discovery, wifite

I am looking to get a list of devices which are in range of my Wifi antenne (monitor mode).

For example: "Tom's Iphone"

I can get the MAC's of these devices, but is it possible to get the name of these devices without them actually connect to my Wifi Antenne?

Or is this something that is not technically possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No  this is not possible. Generally the names you’re talking about come from NETBIOS, bonjour, UPnP, or some other broadcast protocol. These, however, only broadcast within their own networks so unless the device connects and then you capture a beacon you’re out of luck. You could potentially build something that was an SSID of ‘attwifi’ which deauths clients after they broadcast their name if you really wanted to collect device names.